# how to restrict from opening multiple alert back to back?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I have written a angular error Interceptor where i am checking for 401 unauthorized or session expired. it works perfect but the problem is i have used multiple GET apis which on session expire throwing multiple 401. i am displaying js alert and re-directing to login page. as i am getting multiple 401 ,the alert box also is showing multiple times.
ex: if i got 3 times 401. the alert box is showing 3 times back to each.

i used flag to check if one alert box is open make it true and the make the rest false.. but it is not working.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (req.url.indexOf('/reset_password') > 1 ||
        req.url.indexOf('/login') > 1) {
        return next.handle(req);
    }

    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
            alert("Sesson expired, Please Login again!");
            $('.modal').modal('hide')
            this.AuthService.logout()  
        }

        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
    }))
}
```

i want to display only one alert box not multiple. on click of OK i want to close it.

Comment: have you tried `throttle` or `debounce` ?

Comment: no.. can you please explain,hoe can i use here.

Comment: be careful hoe is not what you expected x)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `debounce` or `throttle` based on the requirements, here is an example implementation for debounce.

As you can see it only triggers once, and only after provided time in miliseconds since last call of the function.

```js
function debounce(func, wait) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            func.apply(context, args);
        };
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    };
};

const myAlert = debounce((msg) => alert(msg), 1000)

myAlert("alert1");
myAlert("alert2");
```

You could perhaps change it a little if you want to keep all the messages instead of just the last one. But take into account that i changed implementation of debounce so it isn't exactly a debounce anymore.

```js
var messages = "";

function debounce(func, wait) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        var context = this;
        messages += arguments[0];
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            func.apply(context);
            messages = "";
        };
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    };
};

const myAlert = debounce(() => alert(messages), 1000)

myAlert("alert1");
myAlert("alert2");

setTimeout(() => {
    // here i wait for another 2000 miliseconds so the function isnt called back to back
    myAlert("alert3");
    myAlert("alert4");
}, 2000);
```